# Как сделать игнорирование точек при вводе даты

Tags: c++

Есть структура данных Дата

```
class Date{
int day;
int month;
int year;
}
```

надо перегрузить оператор смещение >> для ввода даты.

Так можно со string'ом, а нельзя никак с флагами?

```
void input(istream& in){
    string str;
    in >> str;
    day = ((int)str[0] - 48) * 10 + ((int) str[1] - 48);
    month = ((int)str[3] - 48) * 10 + ((int) str[4] - 48);
    year = ((int)str[6] - 48) * 1000 + ((int) str[7] - 48) * 100 + ((int)str[8] - 48) * 10 + ((int)str[9] - 48);
}
```

Comment: Пример ввода должен быть примерно: 26.04.2000 в результате чего day = 26, month = 4, year = 2000.

Comment: Вы уже попробовали что-то сделать? Если да, можете показать код? Вроде звучит несложно: считываете в `std::string`, потом проходите по строке посимвольно.

Comment: оператор ввода это не смещение

Comment: У классов по умолчанию поля/методы приватные, поставьте доступ, или используйте структуру.

Answer (score 0):

```
istream& operator >>(istream& is, Date& d)
{
is >> d.day;
is.get();
is >> d.month;
is.get();
is >> d.year;
return is;
}
```

в программе:

```
Date d;
cin >> d;
```